# Getting Error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'" when converting to string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with an object column that I want to convert to a string. I used .astype(str) but it still does not convert the object into a string.

Note: I've looked into the online solutions and haven't been able to solve my issue

````
df['Start_Time']

0          2016-02-08 05:46:00
1          2016-02-08 06:07:59
2          2016-02-08 06:49:27
3          2016-02-08 07:23:34
4          2016-02-08 07:39:07
          ```
3513735    2019-08-23 18:03:25
3513736    2019-08-23 19:11:30
3513737    2019-08-23 19:00:21
3513738    2019-08-23 19:00:21
3513739    2019-08-23 18:52:06
Name: Start_Time, Length: 3513740, dtype: object
````

I have also tried using the datetime library's "strftime" and applying it to my dataframe but I receive an attribute error.

```
df['Start_Time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d%m%Y"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Does anyone have a potential solution? Thanks!

**edit: I was able to figure it out. I was simply substringing incorrectly. Thanks for all the help in the comments! :)**

Comment: They are already in a `str` format; `pandas` treats `str` as `object`. If that string representation is not desired, what is your final expected output?

Comment: In pandas, strings are stored as python strings in an object dtype series.  But because it doesn't use quotes, it's hard to tell if `2016-02-08 06:49:27` in the display is a string, or some sort of datetime object.  The error suggests it is already a string.  I think you need to either extract one of those cells to check its type, or use `values` to get a numpy array (which should show the type better).

Comment: @chris2, the issue is that they are not subset-able (substring-able?). For example, if I just wanted the month for each row, I would not be able to get them.

Comment: @hpaulj 

In the original dataframe, df["Start_Time"] is an object when I do df.info().

When I do, df["Start_Time"].astype('str'), this does not change it from an object to a string.

Comment: An object dtype Series can hold anything - strings, numbers, datetime objects etc.  `astype(str)` produces a new Series (it doesn't act in-place).  That series will still be object dtype, but all elements will now be strings (if they weren't before).  Compare `df[col].tolist()` with `df[col].astype(str).tolist()`.